# Connect Visual studio 2015 c# console application with a specific MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2015, connection

I am trying to connect my csharp console application in visual studio with a specific mongoDB. I have downloaded MongoDB, a mongo-csharp driver and added MongoDB.Bson, MongoDB.Driver and MongoDB.Driver.Core but I still can't connect. Can somebody please help me and tell me what I need to do to get a connection?

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionString = "connectionString";
    var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
    var client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl);
    var database = client.GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);

    bool isMongo = database.RunCommandAsync((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}").Wait(1000);

    if(isMongo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hej");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No");
    }
}
```